# SQL for ignoring rows that have a particular property from a joined table

Tags: sql, oracle

**Update:
thanks for the answers and comments.  I decided to take a different approach and submitted this question:
[SQL to include multiple joined property values, even if property type is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755692/sql-to-include-multiple-joined-property-values-even-if-property-type-is-missing)**

I have two tables: drinks and properties.  They can be joined by drink_id.  Properties have several possible types.  I want to create a query that reports drinks, with their color properties, as long as there is no property for that drink of type "sweetener."

Oracle 11, if that makes a difference.

```
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| drink_id |  drink_name  | drink_brand |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
|        1 | orange juice | tropicana   |
|        2 | seltzer      | schweppes   |
|        3 | cola         | pepsi       |
|        4 | diet cola    | pepsi       |
+----------+--------------+-------------+

+----------+-----------+-----------+
| drink_id | prop_type | prop_val  |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|        1 | color     | orange    |
|        2 | color     | clear     |
|        3 | color     | brown     |
|        4 | color     | brown     |
|        4 | sweetener | aspartame |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Desired output:

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  drink_name  | drink_brand | drink_color |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| orange juice | tropicana   | orange      |
| seltzer      | schweppes   | clear       |
| cola         | pepsi       | brown       |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I was thinking of something like this, but I don't know how to leave out diet cola, since it has a sweetener property.

```
select drink_name, drink_brand, colorprop.prop_val as drink_color 
from drinks
join properties colorprop
on drinks.drink_id = properties.drink_id
where colorprop.prop_type = 'color'
```

Comment: Well, you can select all the drinks that have a property of type "sweetener" and then you can select all the other drinks that are not in this result set. not sure whether the `NOT IN` (also known as antijoin) is the most efficient way to do it though.

Comment: Thanks.  Without removing the "drinks with sweeteners", the result is about 2 million rows, with thousands of unique values for drink_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May have to tweak a bit to accommodate the join, I usually go for old-school wheres so I've just added it onto the end.  Warning: not exists can be a tad slow on really high volumes.

```
select drink_name, drink_brand, colorprop.prop_val as drink_color 
from drinks
join properties colorprop
on drinks.drink_id = properties.drink_id
where colorprop.prop_type = 'color'
/* skip if there a sweetener for that drink */
and not exists
(select 1
from properties s
where s.drink_id = drinks.drink_id
and s.prop_type = 'sweetener'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following relatively simple query should get what you need.  Since drink id is the key that is duplicated, you can use a subquery.  This should bring you your desired results

```
select drink_name, drink_brand, colorprop.prop_val as drink_color 
from drinks
join properties colorprop
on drinks.drink_id = properties.drink_id
where colorprop.prop_type = 'color'
and properties.drink_id not in 
(select properties.drink_id 
from 
properties 
where properties.prop_type != 'sweetener')
```