# SQL to include multiple joined property values, even if property type is missing

Tags: sql, r, oracle, join

This question is based on " [SQL for ignoring rows that have a particular property from a joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711350/sql-for-ignoring-rows-that-have-a-particular-property-from-a-joined-table/29711586#29711586) ."  I got helpful answers and comments, but I've decided to go in a different direction from my original request.

I have two tables: drinks and properties. They can be joined by drink_id. Properties have several possible types. I want to create a query that reports drinks, with a column for each of their properties, even if it is null. If there were multiple occurrences of the same attribute type for the same drink, I guess I would want all Cartesian combinations, but that's not

Oracle 11, if that makes a difference.

```
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| drink_id |  drink_name  | drink_brand |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
|        1 | orange juice | tropicana   |
|        2 | seltzer      | schweppes   |
|        3 | cola         | pepsi       |
|        4 | diet cola    | pepsi       |
+----------+--------------+-------------+

+----------+-----------+-----------+
| drink_id | prop_type | prop_val  |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
|        1 | color     | orange    |
|        2 | color     | clear     |
|        3 | color     | brown     |
|        4 | sweetener | aspartame |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Desired output:

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|  drink_name  | drink_brand | drink_color | sweetener |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| orange juice | tropicana   | orange      | <null>    |
| seltzer      | schweppes   | clear       | <null>    |
| cola         | pepsi       | brown       | <null>    |
| diet cola    | pepsi       | <null>      | aspartame |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I was thinking of something like this, but I don't know how to include rows if one or both properties are not available for a given drink.

```
select drink_name, drink_brand, colorprop.prop_val as drink_color 
from drinks
left join properties colorprop
on drinks.drink_id = colorprop.drink_id
where colorprop.prop_type = 'color'
left join properties sweetprop
on drinks.drink_id = sweetprop.drink_id
where sweetprop.prop_type = 'sweetener'
```

**Update:
As indicated in the comment and answer, my problems were mostly hasty syntax errors.  I could have tested this with the following R code:**

```
library(sqldf)
drinks <- data.frame(drink_id =  c(1,2,3,4), 
  drink_name =  c("orangejuice", "seltzer", "cola", "dietcola"), 
  drink_brand = c("tropicana", "schweppes", "pepsi", "pepsi"))
names(drinks) <- c("drink_id", "drink_name", "drink_brand")

properties <- data.frame(drink_id =  c(1,2,3,4), 
  prop_type = c("color", "color", "color", "sweetener"), 
  prop_val = c("orange", "clear", "brown", "aspartame"))
names(properties) <- c("drink_id", "prop_type", "prop_val")

drinkquery <- 
"select drink_name, drink_brand, 
  colorprop.prop_val as drink_color, sweetprop.prop_val as sweetener
  from drinks
  left join properties colorprop
  on drinks.drink_id = colorprop.drink_id AND colorprop.prop_type = 'color'
  left join properties sweetprop
  on drinks.drink_id = sweetprop.drink_id AND sweetprop.prop_type = 'sweetener'"

sqldf(drinkquery)
```

Comment: That looks like it should do what you want? At least if you include `sweetprop.prop_val` in the select list too, and change the two `where` clauses to `and`. What is wrong with it - are you getting an error, or wrong results?

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  Honestly, I hadn't actually run it.  I put to much effort into making it look pretty and not enough into proofreading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen `WHERE` clauses on the `JOIN`s like you have, but you were close. Making the `prop_type` part of the `JOIN` condition should get you what you are looking for, I think.

```
select drink_name, drink_brand, colorprop.prop_val as drink_color,
sweetprop.prop_val as sweetener
from drinks
left join properties colorprop
on drinks.drink_id = colorprop.drink_id AND colorprop.prop_type = 'color'
left join properties sweetprop
on drinks.drink_id = sweetprop.drink_id AND sweetprop.prop_type = 'sweetener'
```

Comment: I was playing with it also, here's a sqlfiddle that demonstrates @Politank-Z's answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/347877/1

Comment: You never saw notation like that before because it was just plain wrong.  Thanks for getting me back on track.

Comment: @DaveD whoa, sqlfiddle is great.  My whole mistake here was rushing to simplify my real and somewhat large/complex tables and queries.  I really didn't want to create the drinks and properties tables in Oracle, so I ended up wasting everybody's time.  I have updated my question with the R/sqldf that I could have used for a quick test.